# Show that there are no non-trival, two crossing knot

Tags: knot-theory

I am reading this [artical](https://misspaul-math.wikispaces.com/Knot+Theory)
to study Knot Theory, on exercise two, it asks **Show that there are no non-trival, two crossing knot.** From the proof, I don't understand what **branches that do not represent isometries.** And, how does the author know those possible combination can not form a knot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By "branches that do not represent isometries" he means that basically he is just listing all possible combination of the numbers that form a knot.
Then, he eliminate the major part of the list given those "isometries", as rotations, reflection, etc; that is, he compares all pairs of branches he numbered, and look if some of them are the same, to eliminate it.

Finally, he finds out that there are only $7$ possible different knots of two crossings, which are drawn there, and he notices they are all, in fact, the trivial knot.